# Global .gitignore has no effect

Tags: git, gitignore, atlassian-sourcetree

I can't get git to use my .gitignore_global file even though the configuration looks good:

```
PS C:\path\to\repository> git config --global core.excludesfile
C:/Users/UserXYZ/.gitignore_global
PS C:\path\to\repository> git config core.excludesfile
C:/Users/UserXYZ/.gitignore_global
PS C:\path\to\repository> type C:/Users/UserXYZ/.gitignore_global
# ignore settings for VSCode
.vscode/
```

So git should ignore all directories with name `.vscode` and the files inside them. This works perfectly when I add the line `.vscode/` to the .gitignore in the repository. However, it has no effect in the global file:

```
PS C:\path\to\repository> git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   generic/somefile.cpp

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        .vscode/
        generic/.vscode/
        simulator/.vscode/

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

If I add the line to the .gitignore inside the repository, the untracked files disappear.
I am also using sourcetree, but I don't think that's relevant, because the behaviour is exactly the same through the commandline.

I appreciate your help!

Edit: Quotes or not, slash or backslash (single or double), it all doesn't seem to make a difference. With my .gitconfig looking like this, it also doesn't work:

```
[user]
    name = Full Name
    email = full.name@example.com
[difftool "sourcetree"]
    cmd = 'C:/Program Files/Perforce/p4merge.exe' \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
[mergetool "sourcetree"]
    cmd = 'C:/Program Files/Perforce/p4merge.exe' \"$BASE\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$MERGED\"
    trustExitCode = true
[core]
    excludesFile = "C:\\Users\\UserXYZ\\.gitignore_global"
```

My git version is `2.28.0.windows.1`.

UPDATE:
Alright, this was a tricky one. It turned out, there was a section in my regular .gitignore, that made the global file have no effect (even though it was configured correctly):

```
#binary ignore pattern
*
!/**/
!*.*
```

If I understand this correctly, first, everything is ignored, then all directories and all files with extensions are brought back (including the ones I wanted to ingore in my global_gitignore). So the question now is a slightly different one: Is there a way to override this from my global .gitignore? I cannot change the .gitignore on the project level.

Comment: Check to make sure that your global ignore file is a plain-text, UTF-8 (without BOM) file. Windows likes to write UTF-16-LE files and Git does not understand those.

Comment: Thank you @torek, I checked that, and the file is already saved as UTF-8 (without BOM).

Comment: Curious. It seems like it should work, at this point. The line works in the local file, and the setting is correct...

Comment: OMG @torek I searched everywhere for this and you nailed it.

Answer (score 1):

Git for Windows expects the path to be specified using backslashes:

```sh
git config --global core.excludesFile "C:\\Users\\UserXYZ\\.gitignore_global"
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately that doesn't fix it. I have tried almost every possible variant (quotes, slashes, double backslash, ...).